# iphone textfield focus clears the value

Tags: iphone, xcode, textfield

I have 4 textfields in a screen. Consider all textfields have some text in it. When i focus/ click on any textfield the value previously entered in the textfield disappears.
How can I restrict this behavior? Any ideas?

Thanks,
TF

Comment: If my answer worked, please mark it as such with the green checkmark. That gives me nice reputation points ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Interface Builder. There is a setting to 'clear field before editing' (or something like that).

If you're not using Interface Builder, you can find the name of the property responsible for this behavior in the documentation.

EDIT:
I looked it up for you. The property is called

```
clearsOnBeginEditing
```